# Unable to exclude null values from array of objects in Laravel Form Request Validation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

**Note:** Storing 'details' as json field in database

Form Request Validation Code:

```
 public function rules(Request $request)
  {
    return [
      'name' => 'required | string',
      'details.subscriptions' => 'required | array',
      'details.subscriptions.*' => 'nullable | string',
      'details.size' => 'nullable | array',
      'details.size.*' => 'nullable | string',
      'details.notes' => 'nullable | array',
      'details.notes.*' => 'nullable | string',
      'details.price' => 'nullable | array',
      'details.price.*' => 'nullable | double',
    ];
}
protected function prepareForValidation()
  {
    $this->merge([
      'name' => ucwords($this->name),
    ]);
  }
```

Validated result - what I get:

```
{
"name":"Some Name",
"details":{
          "subscriptions":["1"],
          "size":[null,null],
          "notes":["10 pcs",null],
          "price":[100,null]}
}
```

What I want to get:

```
{
"name":"Some Name",
"details":{
          "subscriptions":["1"],
           "notes":["10 pcs"],
          "price":[100]
         }
}
```

Pls help, I am stuck.

Tried this in controller store method:

```
 $validated = $request->validated();
    $collection = collect($validated);

    $size = array_filter($validated['details']['size'], function (
      $value
    ) {
     return !is_null($value);
    });
```

This returns an empty array. But I am unable to figure out what to do next.

Comment: you need a cast 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: You want to allow null values to be sent, but filter then after validate?

Comment: @Svetoslav I have done that.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Tried doing that using filter but wasn't successful. Can you pls help?

Comment: Validation isn't a filter. Where is the code where you try to filter the data you have?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte updated question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter whenever you have a `null` value, then filter again if the array is now empty. There are multiple ways to achieve this, this is only a possible solution.

```
<?php

$validated = json_decode('{
"name":"Some Name",
"details":{
          "subscriptions":["1"],
          "size":[null,null],
          "notes":["10 pcs",null],
          "price":[100,null]}
}', true);

//filter null values
foreach($validated['details'] as $key => $detail) {
    $validated['details'][$key] = array_filter($validated['details'][$key], function ($value) {
        return !is_null($value);
    });
}

//filter empty arrays
$validated['details'] = array_filter($validated['details'], function ($value) {
   return !empty($value);
});

print_r($validated);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a recursive filter.

```
    public function index(YourRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

       $validated = $this->filterRecursive($validated);

       dd($validated);
    }

    public function filterRecursive($values)
    {
        foreach ($values as &$value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = $this->filterRecursive($value);
            }
        }

        return array_filter($values);
    }
```